# Count appearance of a value in a pandas row

Tags: python, pandas, loops, count

Hey I am currently iterating through a column in pandas.
Now i want to handle the case that a value appears only once in that column different than when it appears multiple times.
I tried several approaches but none worked.
Right now I get the error: 
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`
I just try to filter first all rows with the `id` `i` into `df_path_counter`and than i count it is rows in the if clause. I don't know why it does not work.
Any ideas?
This is my code:

```
df_path = pd.DataFrame([(1, 'Germany'),
               (1, 'France'),
               (1, 'Indonesia'),
               (1, 'France'),
               (2, 'France'),
               (1, 'Germany'),
               (1, 'UK'),
               ],
              columns=['id', 'country']
for i, g in df_path.groupby('id'):
    df_path_counter=df_path.loc[df_path['id'] == i]
    if(df_path_counter.count()<=1):
         #...do sth
```

Comment: Use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas-series-value-counts)

Comment: Please include the input dataframe (and code that can be copy-pasted to instantiate it) and the desired output dataframe.

Comment: instead of count() you mean?

Comment: did so @timgeb. any ideas of how to solve it?

Comment: I can't see the desired output df.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, use `Series.value_counts` to create a list of country with count == 1 and use boolean indexing with `Series.isin` to filter:

```
country_counts = df_path['country'].value_counts()
country_1 = country_counts[country_counts.eq(1)].index

df_path[df_path['country'].isin(country_1)]
```

[out]

```
    id  country
2   1   Indonesia
6   1   UK
```