# Do sth. if occurrence of value in a column equals 1 in a panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, count

I am trying to figure out since hours now how to handle the case that a value occurs only once in a column of my data frame. In this case i want to do any action. 
Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,1,1,2,3,3],columns=['id']
for i, g in df.groupby('id'):
    df_counter=df.loc[df['id'] == i]
    if(df_counter.count()<=1):
      #...do sth
    else:
      #anything else
```

So in case i = 2, I want to do sth. as it only occurs once in the column `id`. Otherwise I do sth else.
My approach does not work. Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count appearance of a value in a pandas row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387273/count-appearance-of-a-value-in-a-pandas-row)

Comment: You literally asked this very question a few hours ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387273/count-appearance-of-a-value-in-a-pandas-row). Why not clarify that question instead of posting another? Also perhaps include some examples of what `# do something` is. Depending upon the complexity that can change the answer.

Comment: @ALollz,  I am new here sorry for the duplicate. I just saw that i did not describe my issue very well in the first try.

Comment: @ALollz `#do sth` really does not matter at all. All i want is to handle the case that a value appears only once in a column. In case it appears more than 1 time do sth else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1,1,1,2,3,3],columns=['id']
for i, g in df.groupby('id'):
    count= df[df.id == i].shape[0]
    if(count==1):
        #do sth.
```